# Why isn't the render showing realtime progress?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Sometimes when handling scenes from other users I get a render that doesn't show until it's completely done.

It's probably just a setting that's ticked on or off but I can't figure out where to find this or even what it's called nor what the purpose of this is.

Operating system: Windows 7 professional

Blender version: 2.78

Render engine: Cycles

Occurs both on CPU and GPU (msi GEFORCE GTX 980Ti)  rendering

Some in depth explanation on this matter would be greatly appreciated!
*(advantages/disadvantages/...)*

**EDIT:** *(included a screenshot that shows the settings I'm using.)*
[image]

Comment: @cegaton Done! GEFORCE GTX 980Ti

Comment: This doesn't really look intentional, more looks like a bug, although I can't be sure, when it's done, I presume it gives you an image?

Comment: It is possible you accidentaly changed the slot before you started the render?

Comment: I have the exact same issue in one of my computers running windows 7, blender 2.78, and 2xGTX780Ti:  It renders fine, but it does not update the screen as it renders, only when it is finished.

Comment: @Lukaash Yes, when it's done It shows the rendered image

Comment: @Alphisto I didn't change anything that I'm sure of. As I mentioned, I got the scenes from other users so I'm not certain which features should be enabled/disabled

Comment: @Delagone did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @cegaton No, I was facing this issue with a number of older files. Which led me to rebuild my custom startup file. The issue hasn't occurred since.
I'm still wondering what caused it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to turn off "Save Buffers" in Properties -> Render -> Performance. It helped me in Blender v2.79

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you're accidentally previewing a RenderLayer which is currently not being rendered, or a pass which does not exist within the current render layer. I had situations like this in the past at least.

While the render is running, check in the bottom of the image editor and verify if the current render layer **which is calculating** is really set to be previewed. In the following screenshot, I've kicked off a rendering, which starts rendering Layer A. But before that, I had set the preview slot to display Layer B. For some reason, Blender does not switch back to Layer A when the render fires off, see the bottom section of this screenshot:

[image: empty preview]

Switching to Layer A while the render is running solves the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Yet I'm using only 1 renderlayer. I've included a better screenshot which shows the settings I've used.

Comment: @Delagone Very odd. Is it possible for you to share the file? You could even remove the models contained and just drop in a cube for testing.

Comment: I'd like to provide you something for testing but due to a strict NDA I really can't. hope you understand

Comment: @Delagone sure, no problem.