# Blender Render Transparent Tiles Until Final Image

Tags: rendering

Sometimes when I'm working on a project at somepoint the following issue will occur and I have no idea what causes it, finding information about it is difficult because searching for transparent tiles seems to only give results about rendering transparency.

When the image is rendering, the render will not show the current progress in the image editor, but the tile being rendered will still have the orange outline. The image will display when the render is finished.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skRvK.png)
[image: picture]

Comment: There was [similar question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70933/why-isnt-the-render-showing-realtime-progress) before which wasn't solved as far as I can tell. If possible, it would help if you upload the file here - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and include link. Probably this is a bug hence more testing is required.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the required reputation to comment, so I'm posting this as a reply

I am sure you've found out the issue since then, but for anyone comming across the same thing today:

- Recheck the Render Slot at the bottom of your render window
- Uncheck the Save Buffers checkbox under the Performance Tab in Render Properties